# Python - How to properly access class members if the instance itself is not None

Tags: python

Coming from c++ this implementation looks similar to accessing pointers,
in python is there more elegant way to do this?

```
        if something is not None:
            return something.x
        else:
            return None
```

if the instance itself is not null, then allow accessing its members.

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

For best clarity and easier for newcomers to understand, I believe you can use a single line `if-else` statment in Python:

```py
val = something.x if something else None
```

As mentioned in comments, the above will go the `else` part even if `something` is a *falsy* value, such as `0`.

In that case, you could also add an explicit check for a `None` value:

```py
val = None if something is None else something.x
```

Comment: To be precise, you should check if `something` is explicitly `None`, rather than just a falsy value.

Answer (score 0):

If `something` is known to be either `None` or truthy (for example user-defined types that don't specify a `__bool__` method), you can use `something and something.x`

There is [PEP 505](https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/) which has been deferred, but if accepted (which is unlikely) would allow `something?.x` to get your specific behaviour.

Comment: I think the odds of PEP 505 being accepted are rather low. You can read a (now two-year-old) [discussion on its status](https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-505-status/4612/10), and a [longer thread](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/XZZIV42XGG3EIHRBBCCTTCFPWWSOT7MX/) from last year (with some updates just in the last couple of months). It's not forgotten, but there still doesn't seem to be a consensus on how (or if) it should move forward.

Comment: `something and something.x` is really cool

Comment: @chepner You're right, I didn't make that at all clear in my answer!